# remove extra space around the button when image is added vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how to remove extra space around the image in button and make it fit around the button without leaving any extra space[image]
  Here is the screen shot of the buttons

as you can see there in little space around the image inside the button how to remove that space and make image fill entire button

Comment: Have you considered `WPF`? It gives you more control over every aspect of design.

Comment: Change the `FlatStyle` property to `Flat`, then change the `FlatAppearance.BorderSize` property to `0` (zero)?

Comment: Thank u it worked @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thank u it worked @Idle_Mind – Mps

Making comment an answer:

Change the FlatStyle property to Flat, then change the FlatAppearance.BorderSize property to 0 (zero)?